# Объяснение пунктуации

Tags: пунктуация

Отрывок из руководства по психиатрии:

Первая часть определения — распознавание — включает не только диагностику, но и исследование этиологии, патогенеза, течения и исхода психических болезней; вторая часть — лечение, — (**?**) помимо собственно терапии, включает организацию психиатрической помощи, профилактику и социальные проблемы психиатрии.

Почему мы ставим запятую и тире в случае (**?**) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь независимая постановка знаков препинания: **тире** используется для обособления приложения "лечение", **двумя запятыми** выделяем оборот "помимо собственно терапии".

Comment: То есть запятая уходит "во внутрь" конструкции, если требуется ее наличие перед какой-то частью предложения? Например, "Своими действиями он показывает, как бесполезна платформа — пусть в основном теоретически правильная, — если она не связывается с действительными потребностями людей". Здесь запятая и тире объясняются по такому же соображению?

Comment: В этом примере  "ПЕРЕНЕСЕННАЯ" запятая, которая ЗАКРЫВАЕТ придаточное предложение (вставка относится к придаточному).  В первом примере вставка делается на месте  запятой, ОТКРЫВАЮЩЕЙ обособленный оборот.